# AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Embed'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this code:

```
embed=discord.Embed(title="Commands - Type '/help [command prefix]' for command info!", color=0xff0d13)
embed.set_footer(text="!blacklist, !clean, !clear, !disconnect, !id, !joinserver, !listids, !np, !pause, !perms, !play, !pldump, !queue, !restart, !resume, !search, !setavatar, !setname, !setnick, !shuffle, !shutdown, !skip, !summon, !volume") 
await self.bot.say(embed=embed)
```

and I keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Embed'
```

But I don't know whats causing it; I have tried installing `discord.py` again but this still happens.. is it to do with the code itself or something else?

Comment: Can you post your full program? I get the feeling you're missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is most likely cause by you naming that file or some other file somewhere in your path to `discord.py`. To fix it, just rename your file to something else. Maybe `run.py` or something?