# How can I send an embed via my Discord bot, w/python?

Tags: python, embed, discord, discord.py

I've been working on a Discord bot, and I'd like to make things more custom.

I've been trying to make the bot send embeds, instead of normal messages.

```py
embed = discord.Embed(title="Tile", description="Desc", color=0x00ff00)
embed.add_field(name="Fiel1", value="hi", inline=False)
embed.add_field(name="Field2", value="hi2", inline=False)
await self.bot.say(embed=embed)
```

When executing this code, I get the error that `Embed` is not a valid member of the module `discord`. All websites show me similar code, and I do not know any other way to send an embed.

Comment: The discord.py error handling ignores errors like these, since in production a single error could cuase your whole bot to break. Hence, i recommend putting a try except block inside the function everytime you are testing, it will help alot in terms of understanding the error

Answer (score 41):

To get it to work I changed your send_message line to
`await message.channel.send(embed=embed)`

Here is a full example bit of code to show how it all fits:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Desc", color=0x00ff00)
        embedVar.add_field(name="Field1", value="hi", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="Field2", value="hi2", inline=False)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

I used the discord.py docs to help find this.
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.send for the layout of the send method.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#embed for the Embed class.

**Before version 1.0**: If you're using a version before 1.0, use the method `await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)` instead.

Comment: Somehow now, it gives me a new error. "expected an intend block", and the arrow shows the error in the 'd' of the "embed = "

Comment: Make sure you haven't by accident indented something. Check the indentation of the if statement and that line.

Comment: I'm not sure then. Sorry. Try asking in this discord server https://discord.gg/discord-api or you could try reporting it as a issue on the github. Also someone else seems to of had this issue so maybe monitor that post as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44474955/discord-bot-python-no-attribute?rq=1.

Comment: You should pick a different name for variable "embed", not sure if it can cause errors, bat anyways, `embed=embed` is not that clear..

Comment: @WiseMan I've changed it to `embedVar`. Do you think that name is suitably clear or have any other suggestions?

Comment: change ```self.bot.say``` to ```ctx.send```

Answer (score 7):

> When executing this code, I get the error that 'Embed' is not a valid member of the module 'discord'. All websites, show me this code, and I have no idea of any other way to send a embed.

This means you're out of date. Use `pip` to update your version of the library.

```
pip install --upgrade discord.py
```

Comment: It says that there's a syntax error in the install bit.

Comment: Where does it say you're getting a syntax error? You run this command in the command line

Comment: I had done this in the bot's script, lmao.
Anyways, I tried run this in the cmds thing, and it didn't work. Let me send print. http://prntscr.com/fvjbff

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Norby I'm a **little** late, but you haven't added `pip` to `path`

Answer (score 2):

```
@bot.command()
async def displayembed(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Your title here", description="Your desc here") #,color=Hex code
    embed.add_field(name="Name", value="you can make as much as fields you like to")
    embed.set_footer(name="footer") #if you like to
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: maybe you should point out what was wrong with the code posted in the question

Answer (score 2):

how about put `@client.event` instead of the `@bot.command()` it fixed everything when I put @client.event... @bot.command() does not work you can type

```
@client.event
async def displayembed(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Your title here", description="Your desc here") #,color=Hex code
    embed.add_field(name="Name", value="you can make as much as fields you like to")
    embed.set_footer(name="footer") #if you like to
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1):

**For anyone coming across this in 2022:**

> how about put `@client.event` instead of the `@bot.command()` it fixed everything when I put @client.event... @bot.command() does not work you can type

To this ^, I don't recommend using `@client.event` / `@bot.event` as you'd want to register your commands as a **command**.

If you want to simply make a command with an embed in your `main.py` file, make sure you have something like:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Itents.default()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='YOURPREFIX', description='description', intents=intents)

@bot.command(name="embed")
async def embed(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Title', description='Desc', color=discord.Color.random())
    embed.add_field(name="Name", value="Value", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

**However**, I personally like separating my commands into a `/commands` folder and with separate files for all of them as it's good practice for neater code.

For that, I use cogs.

**/commands/embed.py**

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

class EmbedCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    
    @commands.command(name="embed")
    async def embed(self, ctx):
        embed = discord.Embed(title='Title', description='Desc', color=discord.Color.random())
        embed.add_field(name="Name", value="Value", inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Then import it all into your **main.py** file:

```py
from commands.embed import EmbedCog

bot.add_cog(EmbedCog(bot))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Before using embed

**embed** (Embed) – The rich embed for the content to send. This cannot be mixed with embeds parameter.

**embeds** (List[Embed]) – A list of embeds to send with the content. Maximum of 10. This cannot be mixed with the embed

**TypeError** – You specified both embed and embeds or file and files or thread and thread_name.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!hi'):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="This is title of embedded element", description="Desc", color=0x00ff00)
        embed.add_field(name="Like header in HTML", value="Text of field  1", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Like header in html", value="text of field 2", inline=False)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

[Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Webhook.is_partial)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect on few points listed below.
I am assuming that you have corrected defined `bot` in the Cog (`OOP`)
Still I am sharing the whole corrected code

**Corrected Code**

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class YourCog(commands.Cog): # replace with the real name
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(name='send_embed')
    async def send_embed(self, ctx):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Desc", color=0x00ff00)
        embed.add_field(name="Field1", value="hi", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Field2", value="hi2", inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(YourCog(bot))
```

#### Changes EXPLAINED:

- **Added Cog Structure:**

  Created a class YourCog that inherits from commands.Cog.
  Initialized the class with **init** method, taking bot as a parameter.
- **Added a command `send_embed` within the cog.**
- **Updated `await self.bot.say(embed=embed)` to `await ctx.send(embed=embed)`** ( the main problem was here )

#### Why your code didn't work

- The original code seemed to be using an outdated version of the discord.py library.
  The method `say` is no longer used for sending messages with embeds. It has been replaced by the `send` method in the newer versions.