# Discord.py Daily bonus help needed

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I want to make daily rewards for my bot, like you do:

```
*dailybonus
```

and it adds like 5 coins to your balance.

But, I want it to only execute once per day, I know I would need to use json, but I have no idea of what else I would need to do.

If someone could put a example, it would be appreciatd!

Answer (score 1):

You can decorate your command with [`commands.cooldown`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.cooldown) to only allow a user to call it once per 24 hours.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 60*60*24, commands.BucketType.user)
async def dailybonus:
   ...
```

So if a user invokes `dailybonus`, they aren't allowed to invoke it again for 24 hours.

Comment: It would be specific to that user and not everyone?

Comment: Yes.  The `BucketType` enum determines what category the cooldown applies to (per user, per channel, per guild, or globally).

Comment: error:   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/zorin/Desktop/den.py", line 112, in <module>
    @commands.cooldown(1, 60*60*24, commands.BucketType.User)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/enum.py", line 324, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name) from None
AttributeError: User

Comment: `BucketType.user` not `BucketType.User`

Comment: Also, I have this: await bot.say("You have {} Countertop Tokens in the bank".format(amounts[ctx.message.author.id]))

Im confused on how I would make that into a embed.

Comment: Have you seen this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44862112/how-can-i-send-an-embed-via-my-discord-bot-w-python

Comment: yes, but I format it uncorrectly because or like the ctx.message stuff at the end of it.

Comment: It should just be `Embed(description="You have {} Countertop Tokens in the bank".format(amounts[ctx.message.author.id]))` right?

Comment: embed=discord.Embed(title="You have {} Countertop Tokens in the bank", color=0x00ff00.format(amounts[ctx.message.author.id]))

ends in error:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 374, in invoke
    yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 54, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Coand raised a exception: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: `0x00ff00.format(amounts[ctx.message.author.id])` doesn't make any sense.  `0x00ff00` is a number. Do `embed=discord.Embed(title="You have {} Countertop Tokens in the bank".format(amounts[ctx.message.author.id]), color=0x00ff00)` instead