# How do i make my bot send embeds when responding to messages from discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, embed

The way im programming the bot im not sure how to make the messages send as embed via messages from discord. i can make it send normal messages but embeds wont work idk what im doing wrong. im kinda new so!

```
@szn.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content == 'info':
        general_channel = szn.get_channel()

        myEmbed = discord.Embed(tiitle="test", description="", color="")
        myEmbed.add_field()
        myEmbed.set_footer()

        await general_channel.send(embed=myEmbed)
```

**this is my code**

Comment: What's `szn`? What is the error?

Comment: does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44862112/how-can-i-send-an-embed-via-my-discord-bot-w-python answer your question?

Comment: there is no error, the embed just wont send, and i've tried that link also

Comment: szn is wht my client runs with just a name

Comment: Are you passing an ID to `get_channel` or you simply didn't put it in the question?

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: @discordian, you put "tiitle" as an argument in the __init__ function of the Embed

Answer (score 0):

Things to Note:

1. `get_channel()` requires an ID as the argument
2. `add_field()` requires name and value
3. `set_footer()` requires atleast text

Revised code:

```py
# CHANNEL_ID is the id of the channel you want to send message to
@szn.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content == 'info':
        general_channel = szn.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)

        myEmbed = discord.Embed(title="test")
        myEmbed.add_field(name="Field 1", value="Value 1")
        myEmbed.set_footer(text="Footer")

        await general_channel.send(embed=myEmbed)
```

Comment: still nothing when i type info in the selected channel, ive tried with my prefix as well. 0 interaction or logs in terminal

Answer (score 0):

Something to note is that if you're getting the channel that the message was sent in you can do 'message.channel'

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'info':
        myEmbed.title = "[insert the title of the embed]"
        myEmbed.description = '[insert the description of the embed]'
        myEmbed.color = 0xfc0303 [hex color, you can search up hex colors and then put '0x' in front of it] #this is optional
        myEmbed.set_footer(text = "[text]") #also optional
        myEmbed.set_image(url = "[image URL]") #again, optional
        await message.channel.send(embed=myEmbed)
```

There's probably more stuff to the embed that you can do that I don't know, but those should be easy to look up