# discord ping command (Python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So this is my current code for my ping command:

```
async def ping(ctx):
  await ctx.send(f"Pong!  \nLatency: **{round(client.latency * 1000)}ms**")
```

But I want to make it like this:

[image: example image]

How do I do that?

**edit**: Okay not an embed but what's inside the embed like response time, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is called rich embed.

see: [How can I send an embed via my Discord bot, w/python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44862112/how-can-i-send-an-embed-via-my-discord-bot-w-python)

TLDR:

```
async def ping(ctx):
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Pong", description="Pong", color=0x00ff00)
    embedVar.add_field(name="Latency", value=str(round(client.latency * 1000)), inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like testfile already said.

You have to use a discord embed

For the start you can use a generator. The generator generates a preview of the inputs and a code example for python.
This should help you.

https://cog-creators.github.io/discord-embed-sandbox/