# How to send embed to private message discord.py bot

Tags: discord, discord.py, embed

I don't know how to send embed to private message discord.py bot. I have code like this:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_any_role(admin, moderator, ghostluko)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, arg):
    reason = arg
    await member.send(f'Вас было кикнуто из сервера  :crying_cat_face: \nПричина {reason}')   
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
```

And want to send embed to private messages like this:

```
    em = discord.Embed(tittle = "Help", description = "**КИК**")
    em.add_field(name = "Вас было кикнуто из сервера   ", value = "Причина: " + str(reason))
    em.set_thumbnail(url = 'https://i.ibb.co/mvDpBsw/21321312312.png')
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44862112/how-can-i-send-an-embed-via-my-discord-bot-w-python

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the embed in the `await member.send(embed=)`, so:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_any_role(admin, moderator, ghostluko)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, arg):
    reason = arg

    em = discord.Embed(tittle = "Help", description = "**КИК**")
    em.add_field(name = "Вас было кикнуто из сервера   ", value = "Причина: " + str(reason))
    em.set_thumbnail(url = 'https://i.ibb.co/mvDpBsw/21321312312.png')  

    await member.send(embed=em)   
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
```