# I am making a discord.py rewrite help command. But when i try to send the embed i get a weird response

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make a help command for my bot like the below:

```py
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Help Command", description="The discord bot help command", color=0xe8d9d9)
    embed.add_field(name="Slowmode", value="To add on slowmode do .delay (your amount of seconds for slowmode here)", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Ban Members", value="To ban members do .ban @usernamehere reasonhere", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Kick Members", value="To ban members do .kick @usernamehere reasonhere", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="8Ball", value="To use the 8Ball do .8ball questionhere then the bot will answer you", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Bot Latency", value="To get the ping do .ping and it will show you the ping in ms", inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed)
```

When I use it, however, the bot responds in the channel with `<discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x000001D29A1588B0>` and not the embed

Comment: That's because you are trying to send the embed as the message content. Try `ctx.send(embed=embed)` instead and it will be displayed properly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I send an embed via my Discord bot, w/python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44862112/how-can-i-send-an-embed-via-my-discord-bot-w-python)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in by Lukas Thaler, you made mistake in sending the embed. It should be `await ctx.send(embed=embed)`.

Hope this helps!