# How to fix the discord embed?

Tags: python, discord, embed, pycord

Here is my code snipet, and it dont work can you improve it please
i´m a beginner because of that i need help

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def rules(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    channel = channel or ctx.channel
embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{member}", description=f"Read the rules again",colour=discord.Colour.green())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I send an embed via my Discord bot, w/python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44862112/how-can-i-send-an-embed-via-my-discord-bot-w-python)

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific what is not working? Displaying it in chat?

`embed = discord.Embed(...)` will just give you a instance of an Embed object, that is just locally on your machine, no communcation with discord yet.
At this point you can still can still manipulate before sending it do the channel via:

```py
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def rules(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    channel = channel or ctx.channel
    embed = discord.Embed(
      title=f"{member.mention}", #Mentions the member which looks better.
      description=f"Read the rules again",
      colour=discord.Colour.green()
      )
      await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.