# Discord.py Invalid embeds: <discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x0000023776AF6DD0>

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a simple discord bot with interactions. For some unknown reason, the bot cannot send embeds in its messages (here is a small part of the code where embeds don't work and imports).

```
import interactions
import discord
from interactions import ComponentContext, GuildChannel, OptionType, StringSelectMenu, ActionRow, slash_command, SlashContext, slash_option, Button, ButtonStyle, component_callback, spread_to_rows
from interactions.api.events import Component
bot = interactions.Client()

@component_callback("orderSelect")
async def callbackOrderSelect(ctx: ComponentContext):   
    embed1 = discord.Embed(title="title")
    embed1.add_field(name="embed") 
    
    await ctx.defer(ephemeral=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed1)
```

The bot should send a message containing an embed, but for some reason it considers this embed invalid. I don't understand the problem because this exact embed perfetly works in my another program. When the bot tries to send this message, it throws an error:
`ValueError: Invalid embeds: <discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x000001F69DD063B0>`

Full error:

```
Ignoring exception in Component Callback for orderSelect:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\interactions\client\client.py", line 1818, in __dispatch_interaction
    response = await callback
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\interactions\models\internal\command.py", line 132, in __call__     
    await self.call_callback(self.callback, context)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\interactions\models\internal\command.py", line 198, in call_callback
    await self.call_with_binding(callback, context, **context.kwargs)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\interactions\models\internal\callback.py", line 43, in call_with_binding
    return await callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\HP\Desktop\Ruslaninator\kuznya\main_v2.py", line 85, in callbackOrderSelect
    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="title"))
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\interactions\models\internal\context.py", line 498, in send
    return await super().send(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\interactions\client\mixins\send.py", line 85, in send
    message_payload = models.discord.message.process_message_payload(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\interactions\models\discord\message.py", line 933, in process_message_payload
    embeds = process_embeds(embeds)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\interactions\models\discord\embed.py", line 489, in process_embeds
    raise ValueError(f"Invalid embeds: {embeds}")
ValueError: Invalid embeds: <discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x000001EF02295A20>
```

Please explain what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this problem. If you need additional information, don't mind asking.

Comment: Please post the *full* error.

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44862112/how-can-i-send-an-embed-via-my-discord-bot-w-python

Comment: I saw this page, it didn't help in my situation.

Comment: I dont understand why it is considered invalid

Comment: I think the embed is invalid because you added a field with no value. Use `embed1.add_field(name="field_name", value="field_value")`