# Discord pagination

Tags: pagination, discord.py

How can I make it so that when a button is pressed such as the "next" button the page contents change. I tried .callback but that didnt seem to work that well with some of the variables. The contents are also on an embed.

```
@client.tree.command(name="view-all", description="Shows all videos")
async def view_all_videos(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    page_number = 0

    guild_id = interaction.guild.id
    database_path = f"D:\\VSB\\Servers\\{guild_id}_videos.db"
    conn = sqlite3.connect(database_path)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT name, link FROM videos")
    video_records = cursor.fetchall()

    videos_per_page = 7

  
    video_groups = [video_records[i:i + videos_per_page] for i in range(0, len(video_records), videos_per_page)]

    total_pages = len(video_groups)
    print(f"total pages:{total_pages} page_number:{page_number}")
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Library", description="A viewable list of the library", color=0x4dff4d)

    video_group = video_groups[page_number]
    video_list = "\n".join([f"**{name}** : *{link}*" for name, link in video_group])
    embed.add_field(name="Name", value=video_list)


    footer_text = f"Page {page_number + 1} / {total_pages}"
    embed.set_footer(text=footer_text)


    view = discord.ui.View()
    first1 = discord.ui.Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, label="|<", custom_id="view_first", disabled=(page_number == 0))
    before1 = discord.ui.Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, label="<", custom_id="view_more_previous", disabled=(page_number == 0))
    next1 = discord.ui.Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, label=">", custom_id="view_more_next", disabled=(page_number == total_pages - 1))
    last1 = discord.ui.Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, label=">|", custom_id="view_last", disabled=(page_number == total_pages - 1))


    view.add_item(first1, before1, next1, last1)


    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, view=view)
    message = await interaction.original_response()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create pagination embed menu in discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76247812/how-to-create-pagination-embed-menu-in-discord-py)